# Recovering preloaded data with adonisjs 5

Tags: typescript, view, adonisjs-ace

I've preloaded the data from my DB using my templates, but I can't manage to display them in the view

this is my function in my controller

```
async index({view, response}): Promise<HttpContextContract>{
    const data =  await Structure.query().preload('liste_carte')
    return view.render('pages/list-lot', {data})
}
```

when I do a console.log('data',data) in the 'list-lot' view I'm told that data is not defined

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGgAe.png)